# Test Case Fails on My System but Passes on Others: "Old WebElement Gets Stale" Error

Tags: python, robotframework, automation-testing

I am encountering a perplexing issue with running a specific test case on my system. Whenever I execute the test case of any branch, it consistently fails, citing an error stating "Old WebElement Gets Stale." However, the puzzling aspect is that when the same branch is executed by another team member on their system, the test case passes without any issues.

I have attempted various troubleshooting steps to rectify the problem, including clearing cache, utilizing RCC (Robocorp Cloud Console), and even reinstalling the Robocorp extension. Despite these efforts, the issue persists, leaving me at an impasse.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Always use Locators, don't store WebElements..  Also, 0 code shared so hard to say anything.